# Jasmine specs never complete when run by Phantom JS on TeamCity

Tags: jasmine, teamcity, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to execute my Jasmine specs (v 2.0) on TeamCity as part of my CI process. The problem I have is that the process never exits when it has finished running the specs. I have also seen it exit early with a timeout.  I am using the Teamcity Jasmine reporter.

More detail: I have tried a basic setTimeout-based mechanism found on a blog post (will add when I find the URL) and the standard wait-for driven script on the PhantomJs.org page.  In both cases, the specs never finish.  When running it through TeamCity, the build never finishes, though the log shows that all the specs have been run; if I run it directly from the command line, I see one of two things: either it finishes and then sits there indefinitely, or I get a wait-for timeout message in the middle of running the specs (i.e. it does not finish).

Final detail: this only happens when I include two particular specs.  One is a long spec containing dozens of tests, the other a spec for a simple custom collection type.  The order in which I include them makes no difference.  If I run either spec alone, Phantom exits correctly.  If I include either of these specs with all the others, Phantom exits correctly.  It only seems to hang when BOTH these two particular specs are included.

I have checked that I have no uninstalled jasmine clocks.

The quantity of js involved is too large to post.